# ruby gosu moving image to the direction is pointed at

Tags: ruby

i have been trying to make an image move to the direction it is pointed at.
however it just keeps moving in random directions :(
cant figure out why...

here's the code:


`require 'gosu'`

class Game < Gosu::Window
    def initialize
        super(1280, 720, true)
        @image = Gosu::Image.from_text ':', 100
        @ang = 1
        @x = 640 - @image.width
        @y = 360 - @image.height
    end
    def update
        @sngX = (10.0/Math.cos(@ang.to_f)).to_i
        @sngY = (10.0/Math.sin(@ang.to_f)).to_i
        @n = Gosu::Image.from_text @ang.to_s, 50
    end
    def draw
        @image.draw_rot @x, @y, 0, @ang
        @n.draw 0, 0, 0
    end
    def button_down id
        close if id == Gosu::KbEscape
        if id == Gosu::KbE
            @ang += 10
        end
        if id == Gosu::KbQ
            @ang -= 10
        end
        if id == Gosu::KbW
            @x += @sngX
            @y += @sngY
        end
    end
end

Game.new.show

Answer (score 1):

It definitely does not behave random.

I'd bet the issue is with Math trigonometric functions expect values in *radians* not grads, so `@sngX` and `@sngY` are assigned extreme results.

From the Ruby docs to Math::cos:

> Computes the cosine of x (expressed in *radians*). Returns a Float in the range -1.0..1.0

Hope you know how to convert grads to radians.

Comment: i changed `Math.sin(@ang.to_f)` to `Math.sin(@ang.to_f * Math.pi / 180)` getting slightly different random results. _i dont actually mean literally random just unexpected_

Comment: actually sorry, apparently i failed 2nd grade its `(@ang.to_f * Math.PI) / 180`, its working fine now thanks